# using SCHTASKS command to execute cmd after needed time

Tags: php, windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have successfully created a task, although I am new to use this windows command.

How is it possible to tell schtasks to execute task after 24 H, one time and the start time = (data of creation of file)

```
$command = 'SchTasks /Create /SC ONCE /MO 1 /TN '.date('Y_m_d_H_i_s').' /TR "c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f e:\delete.php" /ST '.date('H:i:s').'';
exec("$command 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

second question : what's the SchTasks argument to execute task one time after 1 month.

Comment: my advice : create a task from the GUI with the corect options. Export this task to xml. Examine / update the xml. You can create a task from this xml with `schtasks /create /xml c:\yourfile.xml`

Comment: I have to execute a php script

Comment: So pass that command to exec as you have done in your question

Answer (score 0):

Since no person have a response for this question, this is my answer :

```
$command = 'SchTasks /Create /SC ONCE /SD '.date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+1 days')).' /TN '.date('Y_m_d_H_i_s').' /TR "c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f e:\delete.php" /ST '.date('H:i:s').'';
*****************************************************************  \n";
```